# How can I use two different versions of the same package with Poetry?

Tags: pip, package, python-poetry

I am using an external sdk in my python application, which is packaged with Poetry.

**#pyproject.toml**

```
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = ">=3.9, <4"
somesdk = "0.1.0"
```

I would like to use `somesdk`'s 0.2.0 version AS WELL AS version 0.1.0.
Obviously when I do `poetry add somesdk==0.2.0`, it upgrades the existing line in my pyproject.toml and I am stuck with only the latest version.

I would like to be able to use both version in my code, possibly by aliasing the package itself of the python import, or both.

Is there a way to achieve such a thing using Poetry ?

Exemple of random code

```
import somesdk1
import somesdk2

def do_important_stuff(legacy=True):
    if(legacy):
        somesdk1.do_it()
    else:
        somesdk2.do_it()
```

Comment: No tools in Python world could do that simply because the very Python cannot do that. Python cannot import 2 different versions of the same library.